# Exchange Server 2007 - EXCDO Event ID 8230's

Tags: exchange-2007

What should generally be done about EXCDO event ID 8230 like the following?

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   EXCDO
Event Category: General 
Event ID:   8230
Date:       3/29/2011
Time:       8:44:00 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   EXCHSRVR
Description:
An inconsistency was detected in jdoe@example.org: /Calendar/Some Appointment.EML.  The calendar is being repaired.  If a problem persists, please recreate the calendar or the containing mailbox.
```

Occasionally our Exchange antivirus product will cause a slew of 8206, 8207, 8208 event IDs which I then resolve by reinstalling it.  The issues go away, but then for days/weeks afterward Exchange comes across corrupted calendar entries in users' calendars and throws 8230's.  It seems as though it's repairing the items and I never see the same calendar entries show up in the 8230's.  Am I missing something fundamental about this issue or do I just let it repair itself?

Answer (score 0):

If my AV software were causing this issue I'd replace it or I'd speak to the vendor about it. Do you have the appropriate file, process, and file type exclusions configured? If not, have a read here:

http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/security-message-hygiene/configuring-file-level-antivirus-software.html

Comment: I've definitely spoken to them about it.  This has happened on two different occasions and the resolution is the same every time: reinstall.  It occurs after upgrades to the underlying Exchange (SPs, CUs, Rollups, HFs) installation.  They have never definitively admitted that their product was the problem or that I should be handling upgrades in a different fashion.  It's something that I now have a solution for (solved by me) and I'll probably be sticking with their product for the near future because it does work well aside from this issue.  Also, no file-level AV, just transport scanning.